# Talend Open Studio for ESB 5.2 Route to Job Optimisation/Performance Issue

Tags: performance, xml-parsing, esb, talend

Using Talend ESB 5.2.0, I want to create a mediation route that will call a processing job on the payload of an inbound request to a CXF messaging endpoint, however my current implementation is suffering some performance issues with large payloads.

I’ve investigated the issue and found that the bottleneck is in marshalling my inbound XML payload from the tRouteInput component to the internal row structure for processing, using a tXMLMap.

Is it possible, using a built-in type converter in the route, to marshal the internal row structure from the route and stream through POJOs or transport objects that are cheaper to process in the job? Or is there a better way to marshal XML to Talend’s internal row structure from a route using a less expensive transform?

Any thoughts would be welcome.
Cheers,
mids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was caused by the format of the inbound XML payload - having more than one loop element mapping to separate output flows from the tXMLMap generates relative links for each item for each output flow, enabling more advanced processing involving the loops if required.
This caused the large memory overhead that led to poor throughput.
Not requiring any more advanced processing in the XML to Talend row conversion, we overcame this issue by splitting the payload to its distinct loop elements using tReplicate and tExtractXMLField components before mapping out of the XML in separate tXMLMaps to avoid the auto-generation of those links.
- mids